# PHP DomXPath - Select html code except header, content and footer

Tags: html, regex, domxpath

I am using DomXPath for the first time and I don;t know how to select some html code.

For Example I've got:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
<title>Dodmond</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<link href="layout/styles/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
</head>
<body id="top">
<div class="header">
header content
</div>
<div class="content">
content
</div>
<div class="footer">
footer content
</div>
<a id="backtotop" href="#top"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
<!-- JAVASCRIPTS -->
<script src="layout/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="layout/scripts/jquery.backtotop.js"></script>
<script src="layout/scripts/jquery.mobilemenu.js"></script>
<script src="layout/scripts/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And I need to make 2 selections. First with the code before **header div**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
<title>Dodmond</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<link href="layout/styles/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
</head>
<body id="top">
```

And second with the code after **footer div**

```html
<a id="backtotop" href="#top"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
<!-- JAVASCRIPTS -->
<script src="layout/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="layout/scripts/jquery.backtotop.js"></script>
<script src="layout/scripts/jquery.mobilemenu.js"></script>
<script src="layout/scripts/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I do this? What should I use?

Thank you

Edit: I found out how to delete all divs, but I don't know how to separate the **code before header** and **code after footer**.

At the moment I've got this:

```
    $html = file_get_contents('..');
    $doc = new \DOMDocument();
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $doc->loadHTML($html);
    $finder = new \DomXPath($doc);
            foreach ($finder->evaluate('//div') as $node) {
        $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
    }
```

which gives me the code in one variable. How can I split it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm not completely sure if you still need help on this problem but I have a `regex` that will match everything before your "header" `<div>`:

```
^<[\w\n\s="<>\/\-,.#!m]+(?=<div)
```

The pattern above would match this chunk of your `HTML`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
<title>Dodmond</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<link href="layout/styles/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
</head>
<body id="top">
```

As for the tail end of you `HTML`, it is a bit too tricky to get everything after your `<div class="footer">` tag, but if you switch it from `div` to `footer`, you can accomplish this easily.  Below is an example of using `footer`:

```
<footer class="footer">
   footer content
</footer>
```

The following will match everything from `</footer>` all the way until the closing `</html>` tag:

```
(<\/footer>)[\w\n\s="<>\/\-,.#!m]+<\/html>
```

*Please Note:* above `regex` includes `</footer>`. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I resolved the footer by adding a comment `<!-- End of The footer -->` and then extract the code after by using explode.